# React - Can't access refs in stateful component event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, electron, refs

I have a class component that has a `onClick` event handler that references an inner ref `input`. However, in the event handler `input` is null. I am binding the event handler to `this` in constructor.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    // The following throws "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"
    this.input.click();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container" onClick={this.onClick}>
        <input type="text" ref={input => this.input = input} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why is `this.input` undefined in my event handler?

**EDIT**
Apparently the code runs fine, just not in my environment. I am using **webpack** and **babel** with the env and react presets w/ hot reloading. I am targeting **electron**.

Full error stack:

```
my-component.jsx:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at MyComponent.onClick (http://localhost:8080/renderer.js:19224:15)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js?:69:16)
    at executeDispatch (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginUtils.js?:85:21)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginUtils.js?:108:5)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:43:22)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:54:10)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/forEachAccumulated.js?:24:9)
    at Object.processEventQueue (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:254:7)
    at runEventQueueInBatch (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactEventEmitterMixin.js?:17:18)
```

**EDIT**

Figured it out see my answer below.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. It will work. You need to write some more detail.

Comment: i ran your code and it worked...

Comment: Weird, it works for me when I run it in an online editor but not in my webpack environment.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue you are describing. Are you sure the test case in your question accurately represents the error you are running into? If I recall correctly, attempting to call a method that doesn't exist on an object **does not** throw `Cannot read property 'property' of undefined`; it should throw `object.method is not a function`.

Comment: [DEMO](http://light-afternoon.surge.sh/) with your code plus style on the container div to make it more visible... check the console to view click event logs...

Comment: ^ seems to fine, maybe more description on your error

Comment: I had issues with refs using the same environment as you. What I would up doing was using div id's instead

Comment: @MatTheWhale I fixed it if you're interested

Comment: @Bob Good for you man! Thanks for letting me know, I'll keep this post in mind in the future.  In the meantime, make sure you accept your own answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it was a problem with `react-hot-loader`. Apparently saving the value of `this` doesn't work in the constructor with `react-hot-loader`. The fix is to manually enable the `transform-es2015-classes` plugin in your babelrc.

See https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/597

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get input value. if yes here is the code. There is no `this.input.click();` method definition

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    // The following throws "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"
    console.log(this.input.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <input type="text" ref={input => this.input = input} onChange={this.onClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: `this.input` is undefined for some reason in my environment.

Comment: Can you try `this.textInput` instead of  `this.input`

Comment: Tried `this.textInput` and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rewriting your `onClick` callback as an arrow function? This will also make your code a little smaller:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  this.input = null;

  onClick = () => {
    this.input && this.input.click();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container" onClick={this.onClick}>
        <input type="text" ref={input => this.input = input} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Even though it shouldn't matter, I also check if this.input is set - but you can ignore that part (usually).

Comment: Tried this using the transform-class-properties plugin and I get the same result.

Comment: What happens if you enclose `onClick={ () => console.log( this.onClick ) }` into an arrow function and log it out?